# 'Windows fatal exception: access violation' with tensor flow object detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip, object-detection-api

so I am trying to create a custom object detector for myself and am using this guide:https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#training-the-model. As I am new to this I have followed all instructions to a T. However when I try to train my model with `python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn -pipeline_config_path=models/my_ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn/pipeline.config` I get the following error:

```
2021-03-15 23:49:57.441253: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
2021-03-15 23:50:08.636642: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 49 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:50:18.699069: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 149 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:50:28.835509: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 234 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:50:39.771722: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 297 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:50:49.312747: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 320 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:50:58.806089: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 360 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:09.810531: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 400 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:18.791169: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 406 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:30.375699: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 442 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:38.994588: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 466 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:49.395020: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 506 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:51:59.317995: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 531 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:09.465026: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 570 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:19.124648: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 594 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:28.983142: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 634 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:38.615317: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 673 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:49.003972: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 698 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:52:59.077313: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 738 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:09.490022: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 763 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:18.937036: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 800 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:29.407881: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 825 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:39.302728: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 863 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:48.757507: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 886 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:53:58.636679: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 910 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:54:09.077197: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 949 of 2048
2021-03-15 23:54:18.762039: I tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc:177] Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while): 988 of 2048
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00000890 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2573 in iterator_get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 730 in _next_internal
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 800 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\multi_device_iterator_ops.py", line 585 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 1619 in get_next_as_list_static_shapes
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 663 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 632 in __next__
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 628 in next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 352 in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 580 in train_loop
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104 in main
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300 in run
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40 in run
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113 in <module>
Windows fatal exception: access violation

Thread 0x00000890 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\eWindows fatal exception: access violation

nvs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py", line 2573 in iterator_get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 730 in _next_internal
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\iterator_ops.py", line 800 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\multi_device_iterator_ops.py", line 585 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 1619 in get_next_as_list_static_shapes
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 663 in get_next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 632 in __next__
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\input_lib.py", line 628 in next
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 352 in load_fine_tune_checkpoint
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 580 in train_loop
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 104 in main
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 251 in _run_main
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\absl\app.py", line 300 in run
  File "C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 40 in run
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 113 in <module>
```

I can't figure out what the error is. Please help me solve this issue so I can create my custom object detector.
Also I am using Windows 10, 16GB ram and all the packages are listed below:

```
(tensorflow4) D:\Tensorflow\workspace\training_demo>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\agnip\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow4:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
absl-py                   0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
apache-beam               2.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     20.3.0                   pypi_0    pypi
avro-python3              1.9.2.1                  pypi_0    pypi
blas                      1.0                         mkl
ca-certificates           2021.1.19            haa95532_1
cachetools                4.2.1                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2020.12.5                pypi_0    pypi
cffi                      1.14.5                   pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   4.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
contextlib2               0.6.0.post1              pypi_0    pypi
crcmod                    1.7                      pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
cython                    0.29.22                  pypi_0    pypi
dataclasses               0.6                      pypi_0    pypi
dill                      0.3.1.1                  pypi_0    pypi
dm-tree                   0.1.5                    pypi_0    pypi
docopt                    0.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
fastavro                  1.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
flatbuffers               1.12                     pypi_0    pypi
future                    0.18.2                   pypi_0    pypi
gast                      0.3.3                    pypi_0    pypi
gin-config                0.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-api-core           1.26.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-api-python-client  2.0.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth               1.27.1                   pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-httplib2      0.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.3                    pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-bigquery     2.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
google-cloud-core         1.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-crc32c             1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-resumable-media    1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
googleapis-common-protos  1.53.0                   pypi_0    pypi
grpcio                    1.32.0                   pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      2.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
hdfs                      2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
httplib2                  0.17.4                   pypi_0    pypi
idna                      2.10                     pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
intel-openmp              2020.2                      254
joblib                    1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
kaggle                    1.5.12                   pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
labelimg                  1.8.3                    pypi_0    pypi
lvis                      0.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
lxml                      4.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
markdown                  3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib                3.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2020.2                      256
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38h196d8e1_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py38h46781fe_0
mkl_random                1.1.1            py38h47e9c7a_0
mock                      2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
numpy                     1.20.1                   pypi_0    pypi
oauth2client              4.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
oauthlib                  3.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
object-detection          0.1                      pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python             4.5.1.48                 pypi_0    pypi
opencv-python-headless    4.5.1.48                 pypi_0    pypi
openssl                   1.1.1j               h2bbff1b_0
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 20.9                     pypi_0    pypi
pandas                    1.2.3            py38hf11a4ad_0
pbr                       5.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pillow                    8.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       21.0.1           py38haa95532_0
promise                   2.3                      pypi_0    pypi
proto-plus                1.17.0                   pypi_0    pypi
protobuf                  3.15.6                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
py-cpuinfo                7.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyarrow                   2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pycocotools               2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
pycparser                 2.20                     pypi_0    pypi
pydot                     1.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pymongo                   3.11.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pyparsing                 2.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5                     5.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.8.1                   pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_4
python-dateutil           2.8.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-slugify            4.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml                    5.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
requests                  2.25.1                   pypi_0    pypi
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
scikit-learn              0.24.1                   pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
sentencepiece             0.1.95                   pypi_0    pypi
seqeval                   1.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                54.1.2                   pypi_0    pypi
six                       1.15.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.33.0               h2a8f88b_0
tensorboard               2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-addons         0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-datasets       4.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-estimator      2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-hub            0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-metadata       0.28.0                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-model-optimization 0.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
text-unidecode            1.3                      pypi_0    pypi
tf-models-official        2.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tf-slim                   1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tqdm                      4.59.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typeguard                 2.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3                  pypi_0    pypi
uritemplate               3.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
urllib3                   1.26.3                   pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
werkzeug                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.36.2                   pypi_0    pypi
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
wrapt                     1.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The problem for me is my training batch was to high. I have a good graphics card, so I thought it could handle the default of 64. However, it crashes every single time I put the training batch size to be over 10. I am able to train at a size of 8.